# Skilled Migrant - Expression Of Interest - New Zealand

Tags: resident-permit, new-zealand

I am selected under "Skilled Migrant - Expression Of Interest" for New Zealand.

The latest message that i received:

> Congratulations.
>
> We are very pleased to confirm that your Expression of Interest has been selected from the Pool for further consideration.
>
> We will conduct some preliminary checks of the information you have provided to determine whether your claim is accurate.  Following this checking, you may be invited to apply for residence in New Zealand.
>
> We wish you all the best with your Expression of Interest.

With the above message, Can i assume, confirmation for "New zealand resident permit for me & my family" is almost done, if the preliminary check states that submitted information is accurate?

If yes, My question is:

After selection from pool, Approximately How many months of buffer do i get to prepare myself from now?  in financial aspect/police verifications/applying for IT job(from home country) etc...?

Comment: Brother, I'm selected in the SMC draw on 11th Nov 2022. My question is that how much time it will take to get an ITA if my claimed points are accurate?

Comment: @ZubairIsmail I forgot everything about this process. It has been a long time

Answer (score 4):

The selection of your Expression of Interest from the pool is based solely on your self-submitted score number. At this point, Immigration has selected your Expression of Interest from the pool for further investigation. The following steps are:

- Immigration checks your Expression of Interest to see whether it is valid and acceptable
- If valid and acceptable, Immigration will send you an official application package
- You fill out the forms in the application package, including submitting financial, medical, police, etc records, and submit that to Immigration
- Immigration carefully checks your application and verifies the information (this may take months)
- If approved, you submit your passport(s) to get a visa affixed

You will be allowed four months to fill out the application forms.

So, instead of saying your confirmation is *almost done*, I would say it is *almost started*. There is a lot of work ahead for you, and it can easily take another six months or more.

Comment: Even if your application is accepted, you may get an outright resident visa or a job-search visa (9 mo limit). I can't find the page now, but they implied that you may not want to have the entire family until you've found permanent employment. Elsewhere, 1-3 mo to assess EOI, 4-6 mo to assess your application for residency.

Comment: @mkennedy yes you are right. I may just get job-search visa.